# Capturing graphical output/plots from R and saving them for later upscaling/downscaling

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2, shiny

Right now, I'm creating  a workflow tool with R and Shiny, but it's within my interest to create some sort of capability to "save" the graphs that are created as a part of the process of data analysis and such.

The code is not designed to facilitate users saving their own graphs in the GUI I have on the web app, but **I want to know if R has the capability to "catch" graphs as they are being rendered or perhaps devices, and then save them to a vector or array of devices for later extraction.** Preferably, the graphs would be able to be upscaled or downscaled--most of my graphs are in either `ggplot2` or the base graphics package.

The ideal process would be the following:

- I draw two graphs, which resize if I resize them in the module I am doing data analysis in.
- When I am finished with a certain process, I will be able to save the graphs to a certain external variable.
- Later, when I am looking over the graphs, I can adjust their size and quality.
- Lastly, when I'm satisfied, I should be able to download all of them (but I'm sure this is already possible--this isn't really part of the problem).

**Edit:** Here's what a plot looks like in code right now:

```
observeEvent(input$outlier_zmedian.graph_density, {
  env <- module_env$outlier_zmedian

  if(!is.null(env$rval$outlier_rw)) {
    withProgress(message='Graphing smooth density plot...', {
      env$rval$density <-
        ggplot(env$ggdat) + geom_density(aes(color=sample, x = value)) +
        xlab("Counts") + ylab("Density") +
        ggtitle("Density Plot of Retained Data")

    })
  } else {
    env$rval$density <- NULL
  }
})
```

Then, that `env$rval$density` variable is printed out to the screen using another `print()` statement on the `output$density_plot` callback.

I was wondering how I could minimize changing this code and the system and make it so that the user can simply download the graph *or*, save the graph to another part of the program which can later be accessed in order to change graph properties such as size, quality, etc.

Comment: Aren't you looking for something like `png()`, `pdf()` or `jpeg()`?

Comment: @PauloMiraMor I'm looking for a way to save the graphs as objects themselves and then resize them if I don't like their resolutions and then save them to files. The problem isn't finding the format, but how to store graphs as they are just "passing" through R and showing up on your screen, kind of like how RStudio "captures" graphical output and allows you to resize for later.

Comment: So, these functions provide these functionalities, don't they? At least that's what I can understand from your question. Try taking a look at it's documentation: `?png`.

Comment: @PauloMiraMor No, I'm not asking how to graph. I'm asking how to "capture" graphs or perhaps their graphical devices as they are plotted, or how to get access to these devices from some sort of global variable or such. **The point is to capture the devices/scaleable forms of the graphs** so I can rescale them later and output them to the format I desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

**1) Use graphs from the `ggvis` package**

If you use the `bind_shiny` function in the `server.r` and the `ggvisOutput` im the `ui.r`, in the upper right of your graph will be a little gear that will let you download the plots as either a SVG or a PNG format.

**2) Use `plotPNG` from `shiny` package**

This function just creates a png file.

**3) Use a `downlaodButton` and `downloadHandler` from `shiny` pacakge**

This works for any sort of plot and a wide variety of format. In `ui.r` have something like this:

```
downloadButton(outputId="MYyraphDownload", label="Save Graph (.jpg)")
```

and in `server.r` do this:

```
output$densGraphDownload<-downloadHandler(
  filename=function(){paste(GraphName(), ".jpeg", sep="")}, 
  content=function (file){
    jpeg(file,width=15,height=6,units="in",res=300, quality=100)
    print(MyPlot())
    dev.off()
  }
)
```

This example assumes that `GraphName()` is a `reactive` that contains the text that should be the name of the file you are making, and `MyPlot()` is a `reactive` with the actual plot to save. This example makes a .jpeg, but you can change that to anything else R can handle.

Comment: how would you recommend I go about resizing and managing graphs?

Comment: I think if you go with a vector format, such as .svg, you can resize etc in any software that can read the files, and it should look OK. You could also change the arguments to the file making functions, such as width, height etc either hard coding or reactively.

Comment: The limitations of the graphing space is more decided by the screen, but it's more likely that they'll be embedded into bigger things like PowerPoints for presentations and such. SVG should be nice, if I can get a handle on it...

Comment: So does this answer the question? Without code it is hard to be more specific as to what to do.